# if-else clause in Linq to entity framework query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, if-statement

Following Linq to Entities query is causing the "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Data.InhouseUnit'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context" exception.

```
IList<FaultReport> faultReports = (from fr in _session.FaultReports
   where fr.CreatedOn > dateTime
   select new FaultReport
   {
       Id = fr.Id,
       ExecutionDate = fr.ExecutionDate ?? DateTime.MinValue,
       FaultType = fr.FaultType,
       Quarters = fr.Quarters,
       InhouseSpaceId = fr.InhouseSpaceId,
       InhouseSpace = new InhouseSpace { Id = fr.InhouseSpace.Id, Name = fr.InhouseSpace.Name },
       InhouseUnitId = fr.InhouseUnitId ?? Guid.Empty,
       **InhouseUnit = fr.InhouseUnitId == Guid.Empty ? null : new InhouseUnit { Id = fr.InhouseUnit.Id, Name = fr.InhouseUnit.Name }**
}).ToList();
```

Specifically, it is the if expression in bold font which causes the exception. I need to make the check as fr.InhouseUnitId is a nullable. If I take out the the bolded expression, the rest of the statement works just fine. I have spent a fair amount of time, in msdn forum and on web, to understand what is causing the exception but still cannot quite understand. Guid is scalar so it should work, right? Even this expression `InhouseUnit = true ? null: new InhouseUnit()` in place of the bolded expression in the above statement wouldn't work. Can we even write if/else

If i try to write an extension method to take away the logic and just return a result, following exception is thrown:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object 
GuidConversion(System.Nullable`1[System.Guid], System.Object)' method, and this method 
cannot be translated into a store expression
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the issue here is that the compiler is not able to compile your LINQ into a SQL query, as it has no idea what the value of fr.InhouseUnitId -- Guid.Empty would be at that time. LINQ statements have to be constant in order for it to compile into SQL statements.

As I do not know the solution to this, I've left this as a comment.

Comment: @DarylTeo, Compilation is fine, the exception gets thrown at runtime. Initially my check was fr.InhouseUnitId == null since fr.InhouseUnitId is a nullable. I have had used such expressions before in LINQtoSQL without any problem. It is entity framework that is probably doing something strange.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are projecting into new objects of the same type that you are querying from. Is that the case? It seems a little weird, but assuming you have a good reason for doing this, you could split the query into two parts. The first part would get what you need from the database. The second part would run locally (i.e. LINQ-to-Objects) to give you the projection you need. Something like this:

```
var query =
  from fr in _session.FaultReports
  where fr.CreatedOn > dateTime
  select new {
    fr.Id,
    fr.ExecutionDate,
    fr.FaultType,
    fr.Quarters,
    InhouseSpaceId = fr.InhouseSpace.Id,
    InhouseSpaceName = fr.InhouseSpace.Name,
    InhouseUnitId = fr.InhouseUnit.Id,
    InhouseUnitName = fr.InhouseUnit.Name,
  };

IList<FaultReport> faultReports = (
  from fr in query.ToList()
  select new FaultReport {
    Id = fr.Id,
    ExecutionDate = fr.ExecutionDate ?? DateTime.MinValue,
    FaultType = fr.FaultType,
    Quarters = fr.Quarters,
    InhouseSpaceId = fr.InhouseSpaceId,
    InhouseSpace = new InhouseSpace { Id = fr.InhouseSpaceId, Name = fr.InhouseSpaceName },
    InhouseUnitId = fr.InhouseUnitId ?? Guid.Empty,
    InhouseUnit = fr.InhouseUnitId == Guid.Empty ? null : new InhouseUnit { Id = fr.InhouseUnitId, Name = fr.InhouseUnitName }
  }).ToList();
```